# FAST Search Server Space Issues

Tags: search, fast-search

on my FAST Search Server 2010 installation I have a 350 GB data drive that the FAST instance is installed on.  It usually runs about 200 GB full at any given time (between the enormous page file and the FAST indexing).  Now the hard drive is full and there is 170 GB of content in this folder:

E:\FASTSearch\data\sprel\worker\build_proc

What is going in that folder and why isn't it being cleaned up?  Can I clear that folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that if the FAST Search Server services are stopped, these files can be deleted without issue.  Required a server reboot for me to unlock the files from the FAST process before I could delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Sprel is the component which works on click-through analysis in your system, adding boosts to items being clicked in the search results.

If you have a lot of queries going on, the files will be copied over to your FAST server, filling up space.

I'm actually a bit uncertain if click-through will help that much. A/B tests have shown that users will click the top X items, no matter the sorting on page 1. Do they click the item because it's good, and continue down to #2 etc, or do they open more items because the first one was not what they wanted?

So any arbitrary clicking of results cannot be deemed positive or negative, and you might be better off turning off Sprel, and not having to worry about the space :) This is my own personal opinion on this, and anyone is free to disagree.